# Binding element 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, typegraphql

I've got a problem when implementing autchChecker in type-graphql

this is my build schema func:

```
const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [SomeResolvers],
    authChecker: ({ context: {req} }) => {

        return !!req.session.uuid;
      }
  });
```

The error that I'm getting is the exact title of the post.

I've tried to do it this way:

```
const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [SomeResolvers],
    authChecker: ({ context: ({req}:any)  }) => {

        return !!req.session.uuid;
      }
  });
```

But unfortunately the ts compiler will yell at me even harder:

... is not assignable to type AuthChecker<any,any>

In case it might help you, this is my apolloserver instance:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({schema, context: ({req}:any) => ({req})});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you use a non-destructured parameter, `authChecker: x =>... `,  what is the type of `x`?. Also, you're supposed to find `any` when you create your server. This is very bad! It should be `const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({schema, context: ({req}) => ({req})});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with this package but I can give you some suggestions from the Typescript side of things.

The [`AuthChecker`](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/05dae42ce3d9cb11c754697685c969275884d69d/src/interfaces/AuthChecker.ts) type has two generics: `AuthChecker<ContextType = {}, RoleType = string>`.  Rather than setting to `any`, you would ideally want to use the types from your specific app.

The first argument received by the `AuthChecker` is a [`ResolverData` object](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/05dae42ce3d9cb11c754697685c969275884d69d/src/interfaces/ResolverData.ts) based on the `ContextType` generic.  If we create an `AuthChecker` based on some dummy type like `{ someKey: string }`, then the `context` object will be `{ someKey: string }`.

```
const myAuthChecker: AuthChecker<{someKey: string}> = ({ context }) => {
  return !!context.someKey
}
```

It does not have a property `req` with a `session`.  Likewise, `AuthChecker<any, any>` has a `context` value of `any` which also does not have a `req` property.

If you want to access that data, you need to create an `AuthChecker` with the appropriate `ContextType`.  Probably there is a definition for that `ContextType` already somewhere in your app.  For the sake of example, I've defined an `interface` that matches the `ContextType` expected by your function, but with all properties optional.

```
interface MyContext {
  req?: {
    session?: {
      uuid?: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Now your `AuthChecker` can access these properties, using the optional chaining `?.` in case they are `undefined.`

```
const myAuthChecker: AuthChecker<MyContext> = ({ context: {req} }) => {
  return !!req?.session?.uuid;
}
```

You can declare the type inline like this:

```
const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [SomeResolvers],
  authChecker: ({ context }: { context: MyContext }) => {
    return !!context.req?.session?.uuid;
  }
});
```